# How to make a fake DOC file containing only images

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, images, documents, docx

I want to convert a PDF file to a DOC/DOCX file. I do not want the fomatting of file be affected in this conversion. Is there any tool to put every page in the pdf file as image in a DOC file. So when you open it in MS-Word, you think it is a regular word file (apparently you can not edit it, because it only contains images.)

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) will let you take a PDF and export a set of images, from there you could select all and drop into a Word document and do a group resize on all the images so that each image fits on one page neatly.

Alternatively you could get ImageMagick to do the image resizing but that may need a little trial and error to get the correct size.

Comment: Thanks. Exporting PDF to a set of images is not the main problem. Inserting each image in each MS-Word pages is time-consuming. The PDF has more than 100 pages.

Comment: If you can get the images the correct size to fit on one page of the document without needing changed inside Word why is doing a multi select from Windows Explorer and dragging them into the empty document a problem?